# how to properly accept props for child in vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, volar, vue-tsc

Suppose you have a component `my-select`, with a template like

```html
<template>
  <div class='my-select'>
     <MyButton v-bind="attrs"/>
     ...
  </div>
</template>
```

`MySelect` does not inherit attrs, instead it binds whatever extra that you pass to the child `MyButton` component.

The problem: if you pass a valid `MyButton` prop to `MySelect` like size="sm", volar will complain

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'size' does not exist in type

My thought was to take advantage of vue 3.3 improved defineProps type support by exporting type MyButtonProp and using in MySelect

```
const props = defineProps<MyButtonProps & {
  ...
}>()
```

Which fixes the volar error, but now those button props are inside `props` with other MySelect props, not inside of `useAttrs()` like I want.

What's the right way to handle this type of situation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its incorrect that volar is giving a ts error when you do not have size defined as a prop. That completely breaks how [fall through attrs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#fallthrough-attributes) are supposed to work according to the docs.

Comment: The only idea that comes to mind is to write some sort of `getMyButtonProps` utility that basically implements `Pick<size | ...>`.

Comment: I found this github issue helpful, still testing different options
https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/1077

Comment: seems like `vueCompilerOptions.strictTemplates` in tsconfig is supposed to solve this (seems like it's actually opt-in) but is not working for me.